# Google App Engine online datastore

Tags: google-app-engine

I have made a few stand alone apps that don't pull too much information from the internet. However, I want to make an app that allows users to post data which is then used by every user who has the app installed, like an online communal DB/datastore.

From what I've read it looks like Google App Engine is the solution and can be used in this sort of manner (looking at the "guestbook" demo app").

Can I use the Google app engine to provide data for an app?

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about an Android application, I think you can.

Depending on what kind of data you wish to store on your GAE datastore,

you can make a RESTful way of retreiving data from your GAE datastore.

For one example, you may be able to retrieve that data as a JSON object

Application sends GET request to the server, and the server responds with a JSON object.